# SQL priority condition

Tags: sql

I have a query like :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  (`field1` LIKE '%search%' OR `field2` LIKE '%search%' OR `field3` LIKE '%search%')
```

Keyword `search` can be any other words. How can i set priority to this query ? I want to search first in `field1`, after in `field2` and then in `field3`.

So if I find my keyword `search` in field1, row with `search` in `field1` must be in first in my results set.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with order by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE  (`field1` LIKE '%search%' OR `field2` LIKE '%search%' OR `field3` LIKE '%search%')
ORDER BY 
CASE 
  WHEN `field1` LIKE '%search%' THEN 1
  WHEN `field2` LIKE '%search%' THEN 2
  WHEN `field3` LIKE '%search%' THEN 3
  ELSE 4
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better split query and union them.

```
select *
    from (
    SELECT 1 as s, * FROM mytable WHERE  ('field1' LIKE '%search%')
    union
    SELECT 2 as s, * FROM mytable WHERE  ('field2' LIKE '%search%')
    union
    SELECT 3 as s, * FROM mytable WHERE  ('field3' LIKE '%search%')
) a 
order by s
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by the boolean result:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE
    (
      `field1` LIKE '%search%' OR `field2` LIKE '%search%' 
      OR `field3` LIKE '%search%'
    )
order by `field1` LIKE '%search%' DESC
```

You need DESC because by default `false` is usually ordered before `true`

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists (select top 1 * form mytable where 'field1' like '%search%')
 select * form mytable where 'field1' like'%search%'
else if exists (select top 1* form mytable where 'field2' like '%search%')
 select * form mytable where 'field2' like'%search%'
else
 select * form mytable where 'field3' like'%search%'
```